# Exclude specific files from S3 Cross-Region Replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I was wondering if there was a way to exclude specific files from S3 Cross-Region Replication. I am aware of the prefix option, but I have a cache folder within my bucket that I don't want to include.

Example:

I want to include the following:

images/production/image1/file.jpg

But I don't want to include this:

images/production/image1/cache/file.jpg

Answer (score 2):

[Seems](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-what-is-isnot-replicated.html) you need to play with objects/bucket rights in order to exclude certain objects from replication:

> Amazon S3 will replicate only objects in the source bucket for which
>   the bucket owner has permission to read objects and read ACLs

and

> Amazon S3 will not replicate objects in the source bucket for which
>   the bucket owner does not have permissions

Maybe will be easier to move cache data in a separate bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but I thought it might be worth updating it with an answer that does not require meddling with the permissions.
 According to Amazon's own documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-how-setup.html) you can choose the objects (using a prefix in the object name or filtering by tags) that will be replicated in the Replication Configuration for the bucket:

> The objects that you want to replicate—You can replicate all of the objects in >the source bucket or a subset. You identify subset by providing a key name >prefix, one or more object tags, or both in the configuration. For example, if >you configure cross-region replication to replicate only objects with the key >name prefix Tax/, Amazon S3 replicates objects with keys such as Tax/doc1 or >Tax/doc2, but not an object with the key Legal/doc3. If you specify both prefix >and one or more tags, Amazon S3 replicates only objects having specific key >prefix and the tags.

For instance, to use a prefix, set the following rule in your CRR configuration (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-add-config.html):

```
<Rule>
...
    <Filter>
        <Prefix>key-prefix</Prefix>   
    </Filter>
```

Comment: OP is aware of the prefix option but it doesn't solve his specific use case of excluding files deep in a directory structure.